# How to get the edited cell's column name?

Tags: .net, datagridcolumn, datagridcell

I want to get a datagrid edited cell's column name.

```
    private void CellEditEnding(object sender, DataGridCellEditEndingEventArgs e)
    {
        var editedTextbox = e.EditingElement as TextBox;

        if (editedTextbox != null)
            MessageBox.Show("Value after edit: " + editedTextbox.Text);
    }
```

With this code i can get the edited cell's value, but i need to know the column name to update my mysql table. How can i get it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

its easier than i thought

```
    var a = e.Column.Header.ToString();
```